# I have the following code trying to add an object to the database

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

```
 if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        FileUpload1.SaveAs((Server.MapPath("~/PicUpload/") + FileUpload1.FileName));
    }

    MasterPackEntities obj = new MasterPackEntities();

    news NewNews = new news()
    {
        title = tbtitle.Text,
        details = Editor1.Content,
        NewsImage = ("~/PicUpload/") + FileUpload1.FileName
    };


        obj.news.addObject(NewNews);
        obj.SaveChanges();
```

does not contain a definition for '`AddObject`' and no extension method '`AddObject`' accepting a first argument of type '`System.Data.Entity.DbSet`' could be found

Comment: use "Add" method http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset.add(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: Where did you get this code from? `addObject` is not the correct casing for a `C#` API method.

Comment: What is the correct? rhughes

Answer (score 1):

```
obj.news.Add(NewNews);
```

"addObject" is not a method of DbSet.